# How to add several sequence numbers to one single sql view in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sequence

what I would like to do is to add several sequence numbers to one single sql view in MySQL. Consider 
the following example table:

```
Folder 1, File 1
Folder 1, File 2
Folder 2, File 3
Folder 3, File 4
Folder 3, File 5
Folder 3, File 6
```

What I would like to get as a result would be:

```
1, Folder 1, File 1
2, Folder 1, File 2
1, Folder 2, File 3
1, Folder 3, File 4
2, Folder 3, File 5
3, Folder 3, File 6
```

I know how I can add one single sequence number to the whole view using variables but I have no idea how to solve my specific problem. Hopefully someone can help me with that.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Johannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using one single variable you will need two, reset the row numbering whenever the group changes.

```
select folder, file,
  @r = case when @g = folder then @r+1 else 1 end SequenceNo,
  @g := folder
from (select @g:=null) g
cross join tbl
order by folder, file
```